# MySQL: Multiply all the values in a row by 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table Person with age as one of the columns having 1000 entries.
I want to update age of each person my multiplying it by 2.

Would it be possible in one SQL query? I am using MySQL database.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, this is possible like so:

```
UPDATE Persons p
SET p.Age = p.Age * 2;
```