# I want to double the price of an item?

Tags: mysql

im new to sql i have to double the price of an item using a transaction. im trying something like this. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
START TRANSACTION
SELECT hsitems.price  FROM hsitems  WHERE parID = 'AX12';
UPDATE hsitems SET price = (price*2) WHERE partID = 'AX12';
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you committing your transaction to the database using the COMMIT keyword?

This might help you: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html

Comment: yes i have and it give me an error :       #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT hsitems.price FROM hsitems WHERE parID = 'AX12', UPDATE hsitems SET pr' at line 2

Comment: There's a mistake in your select line in the where clause. I'm guessing it should be partID instead of parID

Comment: yea i caught all the typos but it contiues to give me that error

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is replacing hsitems.price with just price in your select statement. From reading some docs, that line might be assuming to use the default database rather than the one you are using. I'm more experienced in MSSQL than MySQL so this is purely a guess I'm afraid. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

Comment: yea im new to the sql stuff im a student s anything helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience in mysql, I normally work with MSSql. 
According to this questions it appears what you have is correct [Question 14121492](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121492/mysql-multiply-all-the-values-in-a-row-by-2)

Comment: yes it does look right by that but it gives me the error around the select statement

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out it was a small typo that i was over looking.

```
START TRANSACTION; // i was forgetting this semi-colon
SELECT hsitems.price  FROM hsitems  WHERE partID = 'AX12';
UPDATE hsitems SET price = (price*2) WHERE partID = 'AX12';
COMMIT;
```